# SQL Server 2014 find a point in polygon

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, polygon, point, geography

I do not know why SQL does not detect this point in my polygon

```sql
select geography::STGeomFromText('POLYGON ((51.561283 -0.199251
,51.562136 -0.045443
,51.468985 -0.045443
,51.472407 -0.197878
,51.561283 -0.199251))', 4326).STIntersects(geography::Point(51.519425,-0.127029, 4326))
```

My polygon is valid in result of `STIsValid()` and also is in right direction which SSMS display the polygon:

[image: SSMS result of polygon]

My point is also located in center of the polygon via Google Maps:

[image: google map result]

Here is the tools I used to detect if my points are correct:
https://www.doogal.co.uk/polylines.php

With these data in text input:

```
51.561283,-0.199251
51.562136,-0.045443
51.468985,-0.045443
51.472407,-0.197878
51.561283,-0.199251
51.519425,-0.127029
```

The strange thing is that when I change lat and long to `geography::Point` function the result is true.

```sql
select geography::STGeomFromText('POLYGON ((51.561283 -0.199251
,51.562136 -0.045443
,51.468985 -0.045443
,51.472407 -0.197878
,51.561283 -0.199251))', 4326).STIntersects(geography::Point(-0.127029,51.519425, 4326))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Text string representations of Geometry/Geography always uses the `X Y` convention for specifying coordinates. This means, when interpreted as geography, it defies the usual convention of putting Latitude first.

So you need to use `Long Lat` in specifying your `POLYGON` in a string.

You can see this in your SSMS output, where you can see that the polygon is located just south of the equator, somewhere ~51° East, and not somewhere in London.

Comment: you are right. the problem is i am migrating from mysql which could specify axis-order [link] (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gis-format-conversion-functions.html) when converting to geography data type. do you know how can i have the same polygon info with pairs of Lat,Long and have correct geography data?

Answer (score -1):

You have to flip the values on the `geography::Point` since the first value is the longitude and the second value is the latitude:

> The Point type for geography data type represents a single location where x and y represent longitude and latitude values respectively.
>
> **source:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/bb964737(v=sql.105)

See the following comparison between using the `Point` data type directly or getting the `Point` object with `geometry::STGeomFromText`. **The order of langitude and longitude is different**.

```
-- get the Point from text using geography::STGeomFromText
SELECT geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(51.519425 -0.127029)', 4326).Lat  -- -0,127029
SELECT geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(51.519425 -0.127029)', 4326).Long -- 51,519425

-- get the Point directly using geography::Point
SELECT geography::Point(51.519425, -0.127029, 4326).Lat   -- 51,519425
SELECT geography::Point(51.519425, -0.127029, 4326).Long  -- -0,127029
```

So you have two possibilities to solve this:

**1. flip the values of the `Point`:**

```
SELECT geography::STGeomFromText('POLYGON ((51.561283 -0.199251
  ,51.562136 -0.045443
  ,51.468985 -0.045443
  ,51.472407 -0.197878
  ,51.561283 -0.199251))', 4326
).STIntersects(geography::Point(-0.127029, 51.519425, 4326))
```

**2. specify the `Point` using text:**

```
SELECT geography::STGeomFromText('POLYGON ((51.561283 -0.199251
  ,51.562136 -0.045443
  ,51.468985 -0.045443
  ,51.472407 -0.197878
  ,51.561283 -0.199251))', 4326
).STIntersects(geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(51.519425 -0.127029)', 4326))
```

---

Since you are working with geographical data, make sure the polygon matches the correct area to get the correct data. You can use the following polygon to match the expected area:

```
SELECT geography::STGeomFromText('POLYGON((
  -0.199251 51.561283, 
  -0.197878 51.472407,
  -0.045443 51.468985,
  -0.045443 51.562136,
  -0.199251 51.561283))', 4326
)
```

Now you can use the following solution to check if the Point is inside the polygon:

```
SELECT geography::STGeomFromText('POLYGON((
  -0.199251 51.561283, 
  -0.197878 51.472407,
  -0.045443 51.468985,
  -0.045443 51.562136,
  -0.199251 51.561283))', 4326
).STIntersects(geography::Point(51.519425, -0.127029, 4326))
```

Comment: That's fixing the problem the wrong way because it'll fail to work as soon as the second coordinate passed to any of these methods exceeds 90 degrees

Comment: @ImGharavi - Also check Damiens answer and make sure your polygon is correct. It looks like your polygon is wrong and you have to flip the pairs. If so: accept his answer.

Comment: But be aware (as my previous comment alluded to) that this will only approximately work so long as both values fall within the more restrictive domain of ±90 degrees (longitude). After that point, you cannot ignore that the latitude needs to be passed as the second argument.